# How to debug an ansible custom module in an IDE

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ansible, pycharm

I've started writing a custom module in ansible. I need it go to a URL get some data, transform it and send it back. It's not working and I'd like figure out myself why it isn't. The problem I have is debugging an ansible custom module is proving to be a nightmare.

I've been able to get a pdb working on it, but that's painful. I really want to take advantage of what modern IDEs can do and actually see all the vars at any given time in my module. Insert break points, all of that lovely stuff.

I've tried looking into a solution for both PyCharm and Visual Studio Code and I'm tearing my hair out. If it was just python then fine, but the moment you throw ansible in the mix...

Help

Comment: You stopped typing, what is the actual _problem_ you're having? Ansible modules are designed to read json from stdin and write json to stdout, so I would think the debugging options are quite varied depending on your situation. Are you trying to debug from _within `ansible-playbook`_ because now that I can imagine would indeed be horrible

Comment: Since you did not mention it, did you read https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/debugging.html?